# Oracle Apex Popup lov conditionally value required

Tags: javascript, oracle, oracle-apex-5.1

I am using Oracle Apex 5.1.

I have a select list item (`P28_SELECT_LIST` with values `A1`, `A2`, `A3`) and two pop up LOVs (`P28_LOV_1`, `P28_LOV_2`).

Based on the `P28_SELECT_LIST` value(for `A2` and `A3`) the two LOVs should be made value required.( I Cannot use validations as it is showing two separate error occurred message for two LOV items.

I need the validations to work exactly as it works when value required it ticked to yes under validations. Is there a way to do it? Maybe by using javascript. I have tried setting attributes like aria-invalid to `true` etc. But didn't help.

Any suggestions on how to do it? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please can you put your code here... the query...

Comment: I have added document.getElementById('P28_LOV_1).setAttributes("aria-invalid","true"); in the dynamic actions. on click of save. I am very new to JavaScript btw.

Comment: Yes but can you paste the entire Query like it is in your code.